# How to Add Default Content for all Category Pages Before and After Content?

Tags: categories

I have a coupon site and my main content is under category (store) pages.

I want to add default content to all stores so that i can get rid from adding content to each new store page i create.

Also i want to add default text after content (coupons) in store pages.

Anybody help me? Like where to add content or pass value to function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want some default content if you create a new post in the category "store".

Try to use `the_content()` filter here:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_default_content' ); 

function add_default_content( $content ) { 

    //run only when we are in the category "store"
    //could also be "coupons"
    if ( in_category('store') ) {

        //define your default text here
        $default = 'My default content is here.';

        // this will display the new default content first, 
        // after that the normal post-content you entered in the post-editor will be shown
        $content = $default . $content;

    }//END if is category

    return $content;
}
```

This will check if the current post is in that category.

Look at the line `$content = $default . $content;`

This line will first show our new default content (`$default`) and after this, it will display the post-editor content (`$content`).

If you have not entered any content in the post-editor, only the default text will show.

You can also rearrange this line too:
`$content = $content . $default;`

In this case, the post-editor content will show first, and after this our default text.

So you could create 2 function, one for content before the post-editor and one after.

---

**Update:**

@sammy , OK, I just had a look at your site.
It seems you are using a theme from http://www.premiumpress.com.

The code I posted above works for normal post categories, if you are using a custom type, taxonomies an terms, please try something like this:

```
if ( has_term('term-slug', 'taxonomy-slug') ) { ... }
```

---

**Update 2:**

You said `'store'` is a taxonomy, so I just tested this:

I created a new taxonomy called `'store'` and added some terms to that taxonomy.
I edited some posts, and added some of the new store-taxonomy terms to these posts.

I added this code to my `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_default_content' );

function add_default_content( $content ) {

        // only show the default content if the post is in taxonomy 'store'
        // true if the current post has any of the given terms (or any term, if no term is specified)
        // we leave 'term' empty, we just specify the taxonomy
        if ( has_term( '', 'store' ) ) {

            //define your default text here
            $default = 'This is the default content.';

            // this will display the new default content first, 
            // after that the normal post-content you entered in the post-editor will be shown
            $content = $default . $content;

        }//END if has_term

        return $content;

    }
```

After this, I see the new content "This is the default content.", only on posts which are using the `'store'` taxonomy. Regardless of which term is added.

As you can read in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), if we dont specify any term, the `has_term()` function will check if the post has *any* term of the taxonomy. So `has_term()` returns true.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but when i posted this code in functions . php the site becomes unavailable. Where can i post this code to work? @lws-mo

Comment: I tested the code from my answer before I posted it, as a plugin file. And I just tested it now again in my `functions.php`. It is working without a problem. 

I just copied the above function, changed `is_category` to `in_category` and changed the slug.

See if you entered the correct slug in `if ( in_category('store') ) { ... }`
I just inserted "store" here cause I thought that is what you are using.

Also what default content are you using now?

Comment: Yes am using a wordpress coupon theme from premiumpress, i think its a customized category page with name store.   have edited functions.php as <?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_default_content' ); 

function add_default_content( $content ) { 

        if ( has_term('store') ) {

        $default = 'My default content is here.Get upto 50% off on you order with our verified coupons and promo codes';
        
        $content = $default . $content;

    }

    return $content;
} ?>

Comment: @sammy I think you need to clarify how your theme works! And if you are using custom content types or not. Read about taxonomies [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and about post-types [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). I would think "store" is the taxonomy and "coupon" is a term of that taxonomy. But I cant say and also dont use the themes from premiumpress. I updated my answer because I also tested `has_term` now.

Comment: But why i can't use themes from themes from premiumpress?

Comment: You can use the theme from premiumpress without a problem. But you need to find out how the theme works, and also the correct slugs of your content-types. Because I cant know that, its your installation. Also look at the updated answer.

Comment: 'store' is a taxonomy like 'category' when i add a new store it will be added as ex. abc.com/store/abc1

Comment: @sammy you said 'store' is a taxonomy, so I just created that taxonomy myself and tested it with some code-changes. See my updated answer.